# SMS from website using my credit

Tags: php, android, html, sms

I want to send sms from my website using php and html but I just found that to do this I need to pay a gateway and then add it to my website.

I want to use the credit of my android phone, do you know how to send sms using my credit?

I will give you a beer by paypal if you help me.

Forgot to say that php mail function doesn't works because in my country is not supported to send a SMS by email :(

Comment: You can just use the 'mail' function to send an SMS message in PHP. Most major carriers support it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Nexmo](https://www.nexmo.com/). you won't send sms using your phone credit but you'll use your account credit that you can top up with paypal and other methods and you will just have to call their restful [API](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/sms-api/send-message) to send sms directly from one php code line ([file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)), no gateways...